# Splitting XML file into multiple XML files at given tags

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, tags

I found an example of splitting XML file into multiple files but it does not seem to generate output.

Here is the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
context = ET.iterparse('c:/Users/username/Documents/pyth/test.xml', events=('end', ))
for event, elem in context:
if elem.tag == 'tagName':
title = elem.find('TaskID').text
filename = format(title + ".xml")
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
     f.write(ET.tostring(elem))
```

I have changed line:

`context = ET.iterparse('c:/Users/username/Documents/pyth/test.xml', events=('end', )) from context = ET.iterparse('test.xml', events=('end', ))` as it was giving me an error when i tried to run the script.

I am running it on windows with:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\username\Documents\pyth\test.py
```

How should this script look like to generate output to the multiple xml files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it seems like i have trying to run python script wrong as you can simply run it by double click.
Another thing which was wrong was formatting of code.
Everything is working now.
Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
context = ET.iterparse('C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Tasks.xml', events=('end', ))
for event, elem in context:
if elem.tag == 'Task':
    title = elem.find('TaskID').text
    filename = format(title + ".txt")
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(ET.tostring(elem))
```